# How to pass char* argv[] to pthread_create?

Tags: c

I am trying to pass whatever arguments are passed into the MAIN thread to a "sub thread" I create with "pthread_create".

```
void *threadMainLoop(void *arg){
    char *arguments = (char*)arg;
    printf("arg 1 - %s\n", arguments[1]);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Start of program execution\n");

    rc = pthread_create(&outboundThread, NULL, threadMainLoop, (void *) argv);
    printf("Thread create rc: %i, %d\n", rc, outboundThread);
    if(rc != 0){
        printf("Thread creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_join(outboundThread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not work, can you please show me how I can access the ARGV array like "argv[0]" etc in the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `argv` in `main` is a `char**`, not a `char*`, and so that's what you should cast it back to in `threadMainLoop`.

Comment: Hi there,thanks for the feedback....much appreciated. I am pretty new to C, can you show me how I can cast back using char** in the "threadMainLoop"?

Comment: Hi there, the argv is a char *argv[] according to the GNU tutorial below? That is why I use it that way.....am I wrong? http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html

Comment: Minus 1 for stating a fact  w/o a giving any example of how to do it, even after being asked.

Comment: @MoteZart: I don't mind the downvote, but I'm guessing the reason I didn't respond as requested 10  years ago, is that 14 minutes after requesting an example, Lynton posted an answer in which they had figured out how to cast to `char**` instead of `char*`. -1 for not being online at 6:30am my time, I can live with once as long as it doesn't become the normal rule ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This works now...thanks Steve for the push in the write direction.....

```
void *threadMainLoop(void *arg){
    char **arguments = (char**)arg;   
    printf("args[0] =%s\n", arguments[0]);
    printf("args[1] =%s\n", arguments[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Start of program execution\n");

    rc = pthread_create(&outboundThread, NULL, threadMainLoop, (void *) argv);
    printf("Thread create rc: %i, %d\n", rc, outboundThread);
    if(rc != 0){
        printf("Thread creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_join(outboundThread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was using your answer in a piece of code and I found a big mistake. You must copy argv and must not use directly the argv. Argv is an automatic variable. Argv can be destroy before you use it in your callback. Just add a sleep(2) in the first line of threadMainLoop and you will see that it does not work anymore !

Comment: I am using this code. Is it updated to a working version, or are their still casting problems? I don't see any replies to how to cast back threadMainLoop, just complaint that you should do it.